# Criteria v/s HQL .who is faster?

Tags: hibernate

I have been reading some anwers, but i'm still confused. ¿Why? because the differences that you have mentioned do not relate with the performance. they are related with easy use.(Objetc(criteria) and SQL(hql)). But I would like to know if "criteria" is slower than hql for some reason.

I read this in another anwers

"There is a difference in terms of performance between HQL and criteriaQuery, everytime you fire a query using criteriaQuery, it creates a new alias for the table name which does not reflect in the last queried cache for any DB. This leads to an overhead of compiling the generated SQL, taking more time to execute." by Varun Mehta.

This is very close BUT! i read in another website(http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/tag/hibernate/) This is no longer the case with Hibernate 3.3 and above(please read this: 9) Hibernate is slow because the SQL generated by the Criteria interface is not consistent)

I have done some test trying to find out the differences but both generate qry's and it doesn't change the alias to the table.

I'm very confused. If somebody knows the main reason please, could you help us. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overall, if you use HQL or Criteria to create your final SQL you won't see much difference in performance in the later versions of Hibernate (version 3.3 and above).

To test this you need to create a representative query in both HQL and using the Criteria interface. Then log the resulting SQL from progressively older versions of Hibernate (perhaps using Maven to allow for rapid version changes). You will notice that as the Hibernate versions decrease, you will see changes in the final SQL.

There is little point in attempting to optimise between HQL and Criteria in code since the overwhelming majority of time lost will be in network traffic between your application and the database. Of course, this assumes that you have a well-formed query that doesn't require multiple full table scans over a hundred million rows or something.

The [quoted blog is attempting to debunk myths](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2010/01/26/stored-procedures-vs-hibernate/) so be careful that you don't take the title out of context (emphasis mine):

> **9) "Hibernate is slow because the SQL
>   generated by the Criteria interface is
>   not consistent"**
>
> It has been said that
>   Hibernate can also incur a performance
>   hit if all queries are constructed
>   through the Criteria interface instead
>   of directly in HQL. The argument
>   posits that this is because every time
>   the query builder code is executed,
>   say in a DAO, Hibernate will generate
>   new alias names for the tables in the
>   query. In Oracle this means that every
>   time a new Criteria-based query is
>   run, the database must create a QEP –
>   query execution plan – as it is unable
>   to match the SQL it has been given to
>   any in its cache. Creating the QEP can
>   take 30% of the time it takes for
>   Oracle to respond to a SQL statement,
>   so for the second and subsequent
>   executions of the same (but for alias
>   names) SQL statement, Criteria has a
>   built-in overhead that makes it 50%
>   slower than direct HQL.
>
> This is no longer the case with
>   Hibernate 3.3 and above. **If it was
>   ever true at all is in doubt since the
>   Hibernate team would certainly aim to
>   create optimal SQL wherever possible**.
>   Independent tests demonstrate that the
>   same query is generated by the
>   Criteria interface after repeated
>   calls spanning transactions which is
>   the equivalent of running the
>   application under load. In each case
>   the query remained identical and was
>   therefore able to be cached by Oracle.
>
> There is one grain of truth, though,
>   in that it is necessary to create the
>   query every time using the Criteria
>   interface, whereas using named queries
>   defined in HQL allows for
>   precompilation during application
>   start-up. However, this needs some
>   perspective. The time taken to create
>   a simple “between” query using the
>   Criteria interface is approximately
>   3ms on an average PC. Embedding HQL
>   within the application is not a good
>   alternative since it does not lead to
>   an intuitive mechanism for maintaining
>   queries with differing fetching
>   strategies, and so the Criteria based
>   approach is deemed the better of the
>   two.

So the blog essentially points out that the main difference is that the Criteria interface may introduce a few milliseconds of extra processing overhead which can be avoided by a direct HQL approach. HQL is also a little more succinct in it's expression of the query that many will find appealing.

In short, the difference is so small you don't need to worry about it.